# mongodb duplicate rows

Tags: mongodb

I have 4 fields in my `MongoDB` database `date,source,uid,time`

I want to create index on date but i also want to ensure that no two rows have the same value of `date,source,uid,time`..one way of doing this is this is (as I read in documentation)

```
db.things.ensureIndex({date : 1, source:1, uid:1, time:1}, {unique : true, dropDups : true})
```

but it is using compound keys index..i only want the index on date and i also want to ensure that no two tows have the same value for date,source,uid and time.

please help me how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

To ensure uniqueness you need an index on *(date, source, uid, time)*, and since date is the first property in this index Mongo can use it for queries on just date too. In fact, the index can be used on queries involving *(date, source)*, *(date, source, uid)* and *(date, source, uid, time)*, too.

In other words, an index can be used on any subset of properties that occurs in the index, provided they form a prefix of the index.